# Prononcer le s final

Tags: prononciation

> Parcours, concours, cursus,...

Est-ce qu'il y a des règles qui dictent quand le s final se prononce (p. ex. cursu**s**) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le s final ne se prononce jamais après une voyelle en français, sauf pour les mots latins comme cursus, mundus, etc.

En revanche il existe des mots terminant par s après une consonne pour lesquels le s se prononce comme fils, sens etc.

Voici une liste complete des mots se terminant par un s prononcé:
[link](http://www.lexique.org/moteur/complexe.php?regex=0&nom_champs%5B1%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B1%5D=&champs%5B1%5D=*s&nom_champs%5B2%5D=lexique3.phon&like%5B2%5D=&champs%5B2%5D=*s&nom_champs%5B3%5D=lexique3.nombre&like%5B3%5D=+NOT&champs%5B3%5D=p&nom_champs%5B4%5D=lexique3.cgram&like%5B4%5D=+NOT&champs%5B4%5D=VER&tri=RAND%28%29&sens=ASC&pers%5B0%5D=*&pers%5B0%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B1%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B2%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B3%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B4%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B5%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&database=lexique.lexique3&lienbdd=&Rechercher=Rechercher&nblignes=500&format=html)

Comment: Merci encore ! J'étais presque sûr quant au latin mais j'ai voulu une vérification:-)!

Comment: Au fait, je pense que cursus est un mot du 20e siècle (en tant que mot en français). Littré n'en parle pas.

Comment: Pas tout à fait correct, y'a fils, sens ...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Bravo ! Je les ai oubliés ces mots. Tu as raison. Merci. Alors, la conjecture du latin n'est pas vraie:-)!

Comment: En effet, j'ai changé ma réponse, merci :)

Comment: J'observe que ces mots (fils, sens,...) comportent une seul syllabe et avant s comme @TimLepage dit il y a une consonne. Est-ce coïncidence ?

Comment: En voici, **hélas**, quelques-uns de **plus**: ès, vis, couscous, (auto)bus, ours, as, tennis (celui qu'aiment les anglaises en pension, si vous suivez mon raisonnement), jadis, albinos, aloès. La liste pourrait s'allonger...

Comment: ton lien ne marche pas

Answer (score 2):

Pour les mots finissant par s après une consonne, la prononciation dépend du nombre. Par exemple :
- un os (s se prononce)
- des os (s ne se prononce pas).
Au 19e siècle on prononçait :
- un ours (s se prononce)
- des ours (s muet)
Aujourd'hui cette prononciation est désuète et on entend le s d'ours au singulier et au pluriel. De même pour le mot mœurs, qui est généralement au pluriel, et pour lequel on prononce le s final généralement.

Answer (score 1):

La règle ou la tendance de la non-prononciation de /s/ en finale vaut aussi pour les noms de lieu, de famille ou les prénoms avec des exceptions notables.

Cassis, Privas, Aubenas, Tournus se prononcent /kasi/, /priva/, /obəna/, /turny/ mais on a Arras /aras/, gigondas /ʒigɔ̃das/ pour le vin, je ne sais pas comment se prononce le nom de la commune qui lui est associée.

Dumas /dyma/, Duras /dyra/ mais Marguerite Duras /dyras/, Charles Maurras /moras/.

Alexis /aleksi/ mais Francis /frɑ̃sis/, Stanislas /stanislas/ ou, un peu vieille France, /stanislɑ/.